# Laravel: how to use GroupBy in a collection

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am trying to understand how to use groupBy() using Laravel Eloquent.

```php
$players = playerGame::where('minutes', '<=', 0)
    ->where('update_status', 1)
    ->where('when', '<', Carbon::now())
    ->groupBy('player_id')
    ->get();
```

I get the following error.

> Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'hb_laravel.player_games.id'
>   isn't in GROUP BY

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to achieve? You're performing group by as part of the query _not_ on the resulting collection. Is that intentional? If you're trying to group a query you need to select the specific fields you'd like to group by; by default it selects all (id being the first) so you're seeing that error.

Comment: I would like to group player_id in the query.

Comment: use ```groupBy('player_id')``` not ```GroupBy``` in caps.

Comment: Sorry, it was in camel case in the code...wrote down wrong before

Comment: try to make ```'strict' => false,``` in /config/database.php.

Comment: have a look this link : https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-translation-manager/issues/144

Comment: @Mandeep Gill  it works setting 'strict'=>false